# Priority Queue default ordering

Tags: java, priority-queue

```
Comparator<struc> cmp= new Comparator<struc>() {
  public int compare(struc e1, struc e2) {
    return e1.x - e2.x;
  }
};
```

struc is point structure. 
when I offer:

`（3,1）（3,2）（3,3）（3,4）`

`q` gives me:

`（3,1）（3,4），（3，3）（3,2）`

and when I offer:

`（3,1）（3,3）（3,2）（3,4）`

it gives me:

`（3,1）（3,4），（3，2）（3,3）`.

What's the logic?

Should it just give the order of `key_in` sequence since `y` is not compared?
When I checked API,it tells me "An unbounded priority queue based on a priority heap...The head of this queue is the least element with respect to the specified ordering. If multiple elements are tied for least value, the head is one of those elements -- ties are broken arbitrarily."

Can someone help explain?

Comment: Please add the code of `struc`, and the code you use to put/retrieve the values in the queue. Are you iterating the values using an `Iterator`, or are you using `poll()` to get/remove the head every time ?

Comment: "Ties are broken arbitrarily" means the PQ can do whatever it wants when it sees a tie, including shuffling your input randomly.

Comment: I used a poll() method to get/remove the head every time. Struc class is just a point class.

Answer (score 2):

The *order* is *undefined* here because all your points **tie** with each other since their `x` co-ordinate values are the same. If you're expecting to have the same order, you should enforce that by modifying your `compare()` implementation to take into account their `y` co-ordinate values as well.

And, even if the order was for some reason coming the same, it's incorrect for your program to depend on undefined behaviour for its correctness.

Comment: I agree with you it's incorrect for program to depend on undefined behaviour for its correctness. I talked with my friend yesterday, He thought this might have something to do with its heap structure.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is in the doc you quoted: "Ties are broken arbitrarily" means the PQ can do whatever it wants when it sees a tie, including shuffling your input randomly.

All of your inputs have the same x coordinate, so they all tie, and the priority queue can deal with that "arbitrarily," meaning in any way it wants, without any guarantees.

Comment: I am trying to implement a FIFO method. If they come at the same time, just first come first serve. =.=

Comment: Then you have to add another property to the elements indicating the order they came in; there's no other way to do it.